# DSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString throws 'Invalid flags specified' exception

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, dsa

I'm trying to generate a key pair with DSACryptoServiceProvider.

Here's the code:

```
        var cspParameters = new CspParameters();
        cspParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey;
        cspParameters.KeyContainerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        DSA dsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParameters); // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key

        string publicPrivateKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(true);
        string publicOnlyKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(false);
```

On `dsa.ToXmlString(true);` I'm getting following exception: **Invalid flags specified**. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum keysize property is 1024, see this article: [DSACryptoServiceProvider.KeySize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider.keysize.aspx)

"This algorithm supports key lengths from 512 bits to 1024 bits in increments of 64 bits."

Comment: Wrong answer. Look you're right abut OP using too large of size but change size to 1024 and it still goes splat.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: You must demand a crypto container that supports DH.

Problem 2: Key size must not be large than 1024 (Windows is dumb).

```
    var cspParameters = new CspParameters(13); // 13 = PROV_DSS_DH which is not exported
    cspParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey;

    DSA dsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, cspParameters); // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key

    string publicPrivateKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(true);
    string publicOnlyKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(false);
```

Howevre on testing this you will discover problem 3:

Problem 3: CreateEphemeralKey is quietly ignored by DSACryptoProvider.

Go get a copy of DSAManaged from Mono if you want one that works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. (The source of "Invalid Flags") You have requested an ephemeral key, but then named it. Naming a key marks it as persisted; so you asked for a persisted ephemeral key, and the system is confused.
2. `DSACryptoServiceProvider` does not support the FIPS-186-3 updates to DSA.  You need to use DSA-1024, or upgrade to .NET 4.6.2 and use `DSACng`, which does support FIPS-186-3 (increased key sizes, and SHA-2 (SHA256, SHA384, SHA512) hashing).
3. The default `CspParameters` object has `ProviderType`=24, which is for RSA.  You need to use 13, which is for DSA.  The magic numbers are less magic in wincrypt.h (PROV_RSA_AES=24, PROV_DSS_DH=13).
4. If you want an ephemeral DSACryptoServiceProvider, the easiest way is to not specify the CspParameters object, and let it use the default.

Any of these work:

```
{
    const int PROV_DSS_DH = 13;
    var cspParameters = new CspParameters(PROV_DSS_DH);
    DSA dsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, cspParameters);

    string publicPrivateKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(true);
    string publicOnlyKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(false);
}

{
    const int PROV_DSS_DH = 13;
    var cspParameters = new CspParameters(PROV_DSS_DH);
    cspParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey;

    DSA dsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, cspParameters);

    string publicPrivateKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(true);
    string publicOnlyKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(false);
}

{
    DSA dsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

    string publicPrivateKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(true);
    string publicOnlyKeyXML = dsa.ToXmlString(false);
}
```